# How to find the diagonals of a point in a 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array like this:

```js
const matrix = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 2, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

If the `x` and `y` of a cell is given, for example `2` and `1` (`matrix[2][1]` is `1`), how can I find all diagonal lines (two arrays, each of which contain the points of every cell in the diagonal **in proper order**) which pass through the provided cell? The matrix (array) will always be symmetrical and square (To be exact, I have an 8x8 grid).

Example:

```js
const matrix = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 2, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
];

const cellX = 2, cellY = 1;

// Code ...

const diagonalFromTopLeft = [0, 1, 0];
const diagonalFromTopRight = [0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Bonus points if you are able to find every line, not just the diagonals (vertical and horizontal, but I can figure that out myself).

Comment: I assume the input matrix isn't always symmetrical, right?

Comment: Additionally, are the input matrices always square?

Comment: @yunzen they are always symmetrical and square, though they will be bigger. To be exact I will have an 8x8 grid.

Comment: @trincot both are 0-based. I fixed the question

Comment: Yeah @trincot. Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the rows (and corresponding index) and calculate the corresponding x coordinate on the two diagonals. When they are within range, the corresponding values can be added to the relevant array:

```js
function diagonals(matrix, cellX, cellY) {
    let forward = []; // diagonal according forward slash shape: / 
    let backward = []; // diagonal according backslash shape: \
    let n = matrix.length;
    matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
        let x = cellX - (cellY - y);
        if (x >= 0 && x < n) backward.push(row[x]);
        x = cellX + (cellY - y);
        if (x >= 0 && x < n) forward.push(row[x]); 
    });
    return [forward, backward];
}


const matrix = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 2, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
];

const cellX = 2, cellY = 1;

console.log(diagonals(matrix, cellX, cellY));
```

Comment: It works! Though I'll have to read through that math to find out how though ;)

Comment: It looks like forward is actually backward here.

Comment: Yes, it depends how you call them. I used backward like in "backward slash" (``\``), and forward like in "forward slash" (`/`)